# ms access sql statement select users with role a not b

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I want to select users who have role A and/or B but not role c. I tried this query but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT User from table1 where (role ="A" or role = "B") and (Role <> "C").
```

The users can have more then one role.  Then can have ABC, AC, AB...

Comment: When you say they can have more than one role, do you mean that the column literally can have the value "ABC"?

Comment: Looks like a redesign is needed.

Comment: If a user can have more than 1 role, then, by convention, you should almost certainly have a "Roles" table, which has a 1:many relationship with the "Users" table

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Guys I figured it out

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.User, a.ROLE
FROM table1 AS a
WHERE (((a.User) Not In (select user from table1 where
ROLE = "ROLEC" and user = a.user)) AND ((a.ROLE)="ROLEA" Or (a.ROLE)="ROLEB") 
ORDER BY a.User;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just omit the `role <> "C"` it will *only* get the rows with `role=A and role=B`. Also, looking at the docs, it seems like your parentheses on your `(role ="A" or role = "B")` are unnecessary.